onCharacteristicChanged method is not called in android BLE
Hello in the below code device MQTT data not showing with Latest FW and differences between old and new FW .onCharacteristicChanged method is not called .setCharacteristicNotification called after that not calling anything can anyone help me
Can any one help me what is mistake I did and below are the logs attached
A.java:
    public void getLiveVitalsData(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {  
            if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
                List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
    
                if (getConnectionState() == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) // BLE Is connected after provision as ghatt is connected.
                {
                    Log.e("PesBleDevice", "Inside SendNonce, connection state should be 2 = " + getConnectionState());
                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside getLiveVitalsData| connection state should be 2 = " + getConnectionState());
    
                    //Log.e("PesBleDevice", "gattservices are following -> " + gattServices);
    
                    //check for services for MQTT i.e serviceUUID
    
                    String uuid = ""; //characteristics of RX_CHAR_GUID
                    for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
                        String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
    
                        //readCharacteristicCheck(serviceUUID, characteristicsUUID);
                        Log.e("PesBleDevice", "serviceUUID read upon when connected state is 2 = " + serviceUUID);
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside getLiveVitalsData| serviceUUID read upon when connected state is 2 = " + serviceUUID);
    
    
                        if (serviceUUID.equals(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                            Log.e("PesBleDevice", "SendNonce | Services read is: " + serviceUUID);
                            Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside getLiveVitalsData| SendNonce | Services read is: " + serviceUUID);
    
                            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                            Log.d("jyothi",""+gattCharacteristics);
                            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                                    gattCharacteristics) {
                                uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                                Log.e("PesBleDevice", "SendNonce| characteristic = " + uuid);
                                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside getLiveVitalsData| SendNonce| characteristic = " + uuid);
                                Log.d("jyothi",""+uuid);
                                if (uuid != null && uuid.equals("0x2A25")) // for getting serial number | characteristics for serial number
                                {
                                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
    
                                }
    
                                //uuid is not null and checking for read characteristics i.e RX_CHAR_UUID
                                if (uuid != null && uuid.equals(RX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                                    //Log.e("PesBleDevice", "SendNonce | READ Characteristic = " + uuid);
                                    //Log.e("PesBleDevice", "SendNonce | bluetoothGatt data is = " + bluetoothGatt + "bluetoothGatt size is = " + bluetoothGatt.toString().length());
                                    Log.d("jyothi","uuid"+uuid);
                                    if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
                                        Log.d("jyothi","bluetoothGatt"+bluetoothGatt);
                                        Log.e("PesBleDevice", "SendNonce| Notifying Characteristics");
                                      bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
    
    
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

B.java:
    @Override
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
                Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged Method", "Inside" + characteristic);
    
                if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().equals(RX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                    byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                    //String test = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    String test = new String(data);
                    if (test == null || test.isEmpty()) {
                        findEmptyPacket = true;
                    }
    
                    String startReading = "grid_import_W";
                    String stopReading = "}}"; // this will change as few parameters are added based on that this will change
    
                    //form a required string for Live Vitals to be sent.
                    if (test.contains(startReading)) {
                        completeLiveVitalData = test;
                        //Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "Starting reading = " + completeLiveVitalData);
                    } else if (test.contains(stopReading)) {
                        completeLiveVitalData += test;
                        Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "Live Vital Data complete packet = " + completeLiveVitalData);
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-> Inside onCharacteristicChanged method | Live Vital Data complete packet = " + completeLiveVitalData);
                        try {
                            //Log.e("PesBleDevice", "Live Vitals Data Sent to PesManager File");
                            if (findEmptyPacket != true) {
                                PesManager.getInstance(webView).sendLiveVitalsData(completeLiveVitalData);
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }
                               // bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true); // for testing purpose only. | unsubscribing.
                            } else {
                                findEmptyPacket = false;
                                completeLiveVitalData = "";
                            }
    
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("PesBleDevice", "Unable to Send Data from onCharacteristicChanged to method in PesManager File");
                            Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-> Inside onCharacteristicChanged method | Unable to Send Data from onCharacteristicChanged to method in PesManager File");
                            PesManager.getInstance(webView).sendLiveVitalsData(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        completeLiveVitalData += test;
                        //Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "Other Data reading = " + completeLiveVitalData);
                    }
                }
            }

Logs:
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX, auto: false
D/BluetoothAdapter: isSecureModeEnabled
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=ca7975ae-4b23-40ee-8df7-a278bfd75c24
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX interval=24 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX interval=6 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX Status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX mtu: 247
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX interval=24 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=EA:C4:26:58:9A:XX mtu=23 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e enable: true

